# Dnvm error: Test-Path : The term 'Test-Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnvm

I am getting following error [I did place part of it] when I run Dnvm at command prompt. I have power shell version 4 running.

c:>dnvm
[image]

Please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstall and reinstalling .NET core https://www.microsoft.com/net/download problem was resolved.